# How to hide a particular cell border?

Tags: html, css

I try to make the following table which the upper left hand corner cell has no border, could anyone help?

```
   ----
   |  |
-------
|  |  |
-------
```

Here is the code

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what's your html? And your current CSS?

Comment: @DavidThomas <html><head>
<style>
table tr:first-child td:first-child{
  border: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
</table></body></html>

Comment: I would strongly advise you to edit your question and add your code there instead of posting it in a comment. Putting it in the question ensures that those who are looking at this issue now and in the future can easily see what you have tried and what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS:

```
table tr:first-child td:first-child{
  border: 0px;
}
```

Or:

```
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1){
  border: 0px;
}
```

Try this. Hope it works